# How to get the webViewLink in Google Drive Api v3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-drive-api

I can't figure out where to find webViewLink. According to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files), I should get this parameter when requesting gapi.client.drive.files.list(). But I don't even have a client object! Perhaps my approach was initially not correct. I spied this solution in one article. From the documentation, it is not clear to me how to do this.

```
  mounted () {
   const gDrive = document.createElement('script')
    gDrive.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript')
    gDrive.setAttribute('src', 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js')
    document.head.appendChild(gDrive)
  },

  methods: {
   async pickerDialog () {
      await window.gapi.load('auth2', () => {
        window.gapi.auth2.authorize(
          {
            client_id: this.clientId,
            scope: this.scope,
            immediate: false
          },
          this.handleAuthResult
        )
      })

      window.gapi.load('picker', () => {
        this.pickerApiLoaded = true
        this.createPicker()
      })
    },

    handleAuthResult (authResult) {
      if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        this.oauthToken = authResult.access_token
        this.createPicker()
      }
    },

    createPicker () {
      if (this.pickerApiLoaded && this.oauthToken) {
        var picker = new window.google.picker.PickerBuilder()
          .enableFeature(window.google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
          .addView(window.google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
          .setOAuthToken(this.oauthToken)
          .setDeveloperKey(this.apiKey)
          .setCallback(this.pickerCallback)
          .build()

        picker.setVisible(true)
      }
    },

    async pickerCallback (data) {
      if (data[window.google.picker.Response.ACTION] === window.google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        const docs = data.docs
        const attachments = []
        for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
          const attachment = {}
          attachment._id = docs[i].id
          this.$axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${attachment._id}`, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${this.oauthToken}`
            }
          }).then(res => console.log(res))

          attachment.title = docs[i].name
          attachment.name = docs[i].name + '.' + docs[i].mimeType.split('/')[1]
          attachment.type = 'gDrive'
          attachment.description = 'Shared with GDrive'
          attachment.extension =
            '.' +
            docs[i].mimeType.substring(docs[i].mimeType.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)
          attachment.iconURL = docs[i].iconUrl
          attachment.size = docs[i].sizeBytes
          attachment.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
          attachment.thumb = null
          attachment.thumb_list = null
          attachments.push(attachment)
        }
        this.tempAttachments = [...attachments]
      }
      this.oauthToken = null
      this.pickerApiLoaded = false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you  perform the list request, speicfy the properties [fields](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/fields-parameter)

In your case:

```js
 return gapi.client.drive.files.list({
      "fields": "files/webViewLink"
    })
```

To perform a  `gapi.client.drive.files.list()` request  - please follow the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js) for Drive API which is available among others for client-side Javascript and for node.js.

Another way to retrieve the `webViewLink` - if you know the `fileId` and it is more feasible for vue.js would be hardcode it as

`var webcontentlink = ' https://docs.google.com/uc?id='+fileId+'&export=download'`

Comment: But I don't have client object in gapi api

Comment: So how do you use `gapi.client.drive.files.list()` so far?

Comment: I do not use this method, because for some reason I do not have a drive object in the client object (the client object appeared after I changed during authorization gapi.auth2.authorize to gapi.auth.authorize.